# add GWT-Highchart to Tab in TabSet

Tags: java, gwt, highcharts, smartgwt

This is my code :

```
HighChart chart = new HighChart(title, PIE, data); 
VLayout vlayout = new VLayout(title); 
vlayout.setHeight100();
vlayout.setWidth100();
vlayout.addMember(chart); 
Tab tab = new Tab(); 
tab.setTitle(title); 
tab.setPane(vlayout); 
tab.setCanClose(true); 
tabset.addTab(tab);
```

The `HighChart` class contain the [showcase](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/showcase/#main) example code. 
The result is an empty tab, any solutions?

Comment: Please put more code then any one can help you. it is not even specify which chart are you trying to use.

Comment: i use PIE and BAR charts, example of the [showcase](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/showcase/#main)

Comment: Add code to your question, not as a comment please.

Comment: I am not sure but make sure that it is not a width or height problem once set height and width of panel and chart 100% size and check again.

Comment: it's not the prob, i do it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the ​​`RootLayoutPanel` who did not accept the chart display, a simple replacement by a `layout.draw();` did the trick